# GCC vs clang on generic lambdas: who is correct?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, c++14

Reproduction is simple:

```
#include <utility>

int foo (int&) { return 0; }
int bar (int&&) { return 0; }

int
main ()
{
  auto transparent = [](auto f, auto&& param) {
    return f(std::forward<decltype(param)>(param));
  };
  int a;
  transparent (foo, a);
  transparent (bar, std::move(a));
}
```

clang compiles ok, but gcc says:

```
04a-repro.cc: In instantiation of 'main()::<lambda(auto:1, auto:2&&)> [with auto:1 = int (*)(int&); auto:2 = int]':
04a-repro.cc:9:45:   required by substitution of 'template<class auto:1, class auto:2> main()::<lambda(auto:1, auto:2&&)>::operator decltype (((main()::<lambda(auto:1, auto:2&&)>)0u).operator()(static_cast<auto:1>(<anonymous>), static_cast<auto:2&&>(<anonymous>))) (*)(auto:1, auto:2&&)() const [with auto:1 = int (*)(int&); auto:2 = int]'
04a-repro.cc:13:22:   required from here
04a-repro.cc:10:13: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'int&' from an rvalue of type 'int'
     return f(std::forward<decltype(param)>(param));
            ~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

GCC information:

```
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ../src/configure --with-gmp=/c/temp/gcc/gmp --with-mpfr=/c/temp/gcc/mpfr --with-mpc=/c/temp/gcc/mpc --enable-languages=c,c++ --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --disable-multilib --prefix=/c/temp/gcc/dest --with-sysroot=/c/temp/gcc/dest --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-nls --disable-shared --disable-win32-registry --enable-checking=release --with-tune=haswell Thread model: win32
gcc version 6.1.0 (GCC)
```

Also I will ask the same question on GCC mailing list, so please do not redirect me there.

UPD: found [this bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=70942) in Bugzilla, it seems like the same GCC issue, already filed.

Comment: Counting them on my fingers, line 13 appears to be the first call to transparent() (you should really clarify this). gcc appears to be complaining about binding an lvalue to an `&&` parameter. I'm with gcc on this one.

Comment: [Works](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/AHQF9LnXJeZHXNpn) as of gcc6.2, so bug in gcc6.1 and older it seems.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: That is not what the error says. At all!